# Proof of stars and bars formula

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I am trying to prove a formula (for ways of distributing $n$ identical balls among $r$ persons when each person may get any number of balls) ${n+r-1}\choose{r-1}$. But I am not able to prove it. I may be doing something wrong but I am not able to figure out what exactly?

This is what I am doing.

I put $n$ identical balls in a line. Now there are $(n+1)$ spaces/gaps between these $n$ identical things including (left to the leftmost ball and the next to the rightmost ball). So now basically I just need to select any $(r-1)$ gaps from these $(n+1)$ gaps and I will be able to create $r$ groups.

So, my answer is ${n+1}\choose{r-1}$.

But the actual answer to this is ${n+r-1}\choose{r-1}$ as per [Number of ways of distributing n identical objects among r groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47345/number-of-ways-of-distributing-n-identical-objects-among-r-groups)

I want to know what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Your approach doesn't seem to allow for empty boxes: if I'm only placing dividers between the pre-existing gaps, then putting dividers in two "consecutive" gaps still always leaves a ball between the two gaps.

Comment: ^ exactly. You aren't choosing gaps between balls; you are literally choosing balls. The chosen balls become the boundaries of the boxes.

Comment: @GregoryJ.Puleo in the following example, there are 6 balls and I need to divide them in say (0 , 0, 6) groups, meaning 1 group having 0 balls, 2nd having 0 balls and 3rd having 6 balls. I can choose the first gap and the last gap to achieve this. 'g' represents gaps and 'b' represents balls. g b b b b b b g . What is wrong here?

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 please see my above comment!

Comment: "What is wrong here?" - you claim to have demonstrated (0,0,6). How would you demonstrate (0,6,0) or (6,0,0)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fault lies in our inability to "choose" a bar twice (which we would need to do for empty inner bins).

Consider ten stars and four bars (corresponding to five bins):

```
*|**|**|****|*
```

There are five bins. The first starts on the left and goes until the first "|". The final bin begins with the final "|", and goes right from there.

```
**|***|*|****|
```

Now the right-most bin is empty. This is all well and good, but what if we want an inner bin to be empty? **We must choose the same "place" twice**, which we can't do.

So instead of only counting the spaces between (and beside) the "*" characters above, we allow for **fourteen characters** - ten stars and four bars. We can choose adjacent characters to be bars to represent an (inner) empty bin.

```
**|***||****|*
```

$(2,3,0,4,1)$