# Why do we add $k$ and $1$ to $n$ in $\frac{(n+k-1)!}{{k!}{(n-1)!}}$ for combinations with repeating elements?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

What is the meaning of adding $k$, and $1$, to $n$ in $\frac{(n+k-1)!}{{k!}{(n-1)!}}$, $C^i_{n,k}$, and how to visualise the components of this formula?

Here is my research:

[image: Maths journal page of documentation of reasoning]

Comment: Are you sure you mean $\frac{(n+k+1)!}{k!(n-1)!}$? Or is it $\frac{(n+k-1)!}{k!(n-1)!}$?

Comment: Can you clarify what the research image is describing?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)

Comment: Thanks for the links, suggestions, and Stars and Bars! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1416132/proof-of-stars-and-bars-formula