# Number of matrices $A \in \{-1,0,1\}^{3 \times 3}$ such that the trace of $A A^{T}$ is $3$

Tags: combinatorics, matrices

> The number of $3 \times 3$ matrices $A,$ with entries from the set $\{-1,0,1\}$ such that the sum of the diagonal elements of $AA^{T}$ is $3$, is __ .

What I tried:

Let $\displaystyle A=\begin{pmatrix}
 a& b & c\\ 
 d& e & f \\ 
 g& h & i 
\end{pmatrix}$ and $\displaystyle A^{T}=\begin{pmatrix}
 a& d & g \\ 
 b& e & h \\ 
c & f  & i
\end{pmatrix}$

$$AA^{T}=\begin{pmatrix}
\sum a^2 & .. & ..\\ 
.. & \sum d^2  &.. \\ 
 ..&  ...& \sum g^2 
\end{pmatrix}$$

Given $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2+e^2+f^2+g^2+h^2+i^2=3$

given $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i\in \{-1,0,1\}$

Out of $ 9 ,$ any three is $1$ and rest all are zero(like $1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0$)

$$\binom{9}{3}\cdot \frac{9!}{6!\cdot 3!}=$$

but answer is different. How do I solve it? Help me, please.

Comment: Do you know: $(-1)(-1)=1$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Number of ways of distributing n identical objects among r groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47345/number-of-ways-of-distributing-n-identical-objects-among-r-groups)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are very close.

First choose three of the slots out of the $9$ to set the corresponding square, $x^2$ to $1$.  Each each of the location, we have two choices.

Hence $$2^3 \cdot \binom{9}{3}$$

Answer (score 2):

For the first part you could have relied on the fact that $tr(AA^T)=\|A\|_F^2=\sum_i\sum_ja_{ij}^2.$

Out of the 9 elements of $A$, exactly 3 must be nonzero, and their sign can be positive or negative, so
$$
2^3 {9\choose 3}.
$$