# Distribution of 13 identical books to 5 students and each has to receive at least one book.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

Could someone please confirm my answer?

To solve this problem, we can use the concept of distributing identical items (exercise books) to distinct recipients (students) with a constraint (each student must receive at least one book).

Since each of the 5 students must receive at least one book, we first give one book to each student. So we are left with 13 - 5 = 8 books.

The problem becomes one of distributing 8 identical books among 5 students without any restrictions.

To my understanding, the formula for the number of ways to distribute n identical items among k recipients is:

(n + k - 1
k - 1)

In our case:

(8 + 5 - 1
5 - 1)

which equals to 495.

Am I getting it right?

Comment: Could you use mathjax to make it clearer?

Comment: Please see [Number of ways of distributing $n$ identical objects among $r$ groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47345/number-of-ways-of-distributing-n-identical-objects-among-r-groups) and linked question.